# Change color of transparent image in Qt

Tags: qt, qimage

I have a transparent image (QImage) overlayed over a video in Qt. I want to change the color of the transparent image only on clicks of button. Can some one tell me how to do this?

Thank You.

Comment: have 2 images and swap between them

Comment: But I want to set different ranges for the color. It need not be a fixed color. If this the case then what can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the color"?

Comment: The transparent image is in black color. Based on the slider movement or button click the color has to change in rgb values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done in many ways. I suggest to use `QPainter` to create new image. If you set `SourceIn` composition mode, starting image's alpha channel will be applied to any drawing that you will do. You just need to fill image with desired color.

```
QPixmap source_image; // should be preserved in a class member variable
QRgb base_color; // desired image color

QPixmap new_image = source_image;
QPainter painter(&new_image);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
painter.fillRect(new_image.rect(), base_color);
painter.end();

ui->label->setPixmap(new_image); // showing result
```

Note that I use `QPixmap` instead of `QImage` because `QPixmap`s are more efficient to display (and possibly paint). If you for some reason still want to use `QImage`, this code will work with `QImage` without any changes (excluding the last line of course).

Source image: [image: source image]       
Result: [image: result]

Comment: I tried this method. It is saying cannot paint on an image with the QImage::Format_Indexed8 format.
Is it because it is a png transparent image.

Comment: I tried using image->setColor since it is a format8 image. In this case it paints even the area which is transparent. I want only the non transparent part to take a color.
Thank You

Comment: Indexed8 format is not necessary for transparency. ARGB32 format is commonly used. Use `source_image = source_image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);` to convert image to paintable format.

Comment: Doesn't work at least on Qt 5.3.1, 32 bit on OS X, or may I am doing something wrong. I am trying with QImage only instead of QPixmap, since I need to use `source_image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);`. In place of `base_color` I used `painter.fillRect(new_image.rect(), QColor("red");` . I am getting a blank label.